# Estou criando uma fila, e não consigo desenvolver a lógica da função para que o objeto anterior assuma a nova posição liberada - C#

Tags: c#, c, unity3d

Estou usando a unity3D, por isso minha fila é composta por GameObjects, são 7 GameObjects enfileirados um ao lado do outro e meu intuito com este código é que a cada clique do usuário - "*Função SimpleMove*" - os objetos andem uma posição para frente, menos o ultimo, este deve assumir a ultima posição.

Na Unity é possível associar os GameObjects pela interface, então consideres os dois arrays cheios já no começo.

Gostaria de ajuda para entender e desenvolver a lógica na "*Função SimpleMove*" que faça esta movimentação. Obrigado

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class StairsController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] degrau;
    Vector3[] positionArray = new Vector3[7];

    private int i = 6;
    private int a = 6;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        positionArray [i-6] = degrau[a-6].transform.position; 
        Debug.Log (positionArray [i-6]);

        positionArray [i-5] = degrau[a-5].transform.position;
        Debug.Log (positionArray [i-5]);

        positionArray [i-4] = degrau[a-4].transform.position;
        Debug.Log (positionArray [i-4]);

        positionArray [i-3] = degrau[a-3].transform.position;
        Debug.Log (positionArray [i-3]);

        positionArray [i-2] = degrau[a-2].transform.position;
        Debug.Log (positionArray [i-2]);

        positionArray [i-1] = degrau[a-1].transform.position;
        Debug.Log (positionArray [i-1]);

        positionArray [i] = degrau[a].transform.position;
        Debug.Log (positionArray [i]);
    }

    public void SimpleMov (){
        degrau [a].transform.position = positionArray [i - 1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Grande dica: só use array para estruturas de tamanho único que não precisem de modificação, para tamanhos variáveis e outras firulas use "List" é muito mais fácil é você terá grande economia de processamento.

Você irá precisar de

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Para iniciar

```
List<GameObject> degrau= new List<GameObject>();
```

Para adicionar elementos

```
degrau.Add(**teu degrau aqui**);
```

Para remover o elemento tem várias opções, mas este deve ser o mais indicado.

```
degrau.RemoveAt(int index)
```

e

```
degrau.Clear()
```

para limpar

> Mais informações sobre lista
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Não tenho um vídeo específicos para lista, mas uso ela neste vídeo aqui
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5U3d9iwHm2I

Comment: Como posso mover objetos entre as posições desta lista?

Comment: Você disse ter elementos em sequencia, 1,2,3,4
Quer que eles andem para a frente e o último mantenha a última posição.
2,3,4. É só remover o primeiro.
Se você quiser trocar objetos de lugar, existem diversas funções no link que mandei no final, vários tipos de sort. E se quiser pode fazer uma função própria como está aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094239/swap-two-items-in-listt

Comment: Se você quer que o PRIMEIRO assuma a última posição, como numa escada rolante pode tentar usar Queue (first in, first out). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Neste caso, se for manter o tamanho fixo, pode-se usar array, ai é só colocar um index para dizer onde é o "início da fila".

Comment: Sim, eu conversei com um cara do Stack OverFlow em inglês para discutir este problema e pareceu muito mais complicado do que inicialmente, resolvemos utilizando dois for que percorriam a lista e sempre começavam de uma posição a frente, mas que também zeravam quando encontravam o ultimo elemento.

Comment: Que estranho, me parece bem simples a solução. Existe alguma informação que você passou para ele e não passou para gente? Ou passou de forma diferente?